# Retrofit giving 'No Internet' error even when phone is connected to internet

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit library to download JSON and process it with GSON to show results in recyclerview. However some of my users are complaining that they get 'no internet' error even when they are connected online. Can some one point out what I am missing in my code. Thanks in advance.

Here is my api code.

```
public class BhartiAPI {
public static final String url = "https://www.ddbharat.com/api/";

public static PostService postService = null;

public static PostService getService() {

    if(postService == null) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60 / 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .cache(null)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);
    }
    return postService;
}

public interface PostService {
    @Headers("Cache-Control: no-cache")
    @POST
    Call<PostList> getPostList(@Url String url);
}
```

And this is how I am calling it.

```
final String url = BhartiAPI.url + fileName;
final Call<PostList> postList = BhartiAPI.getService().getPostList(url);

postList.enqueue(new Callback<PostList>() {
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PostList> call, Response<PostList> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                noNet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                list = response.body();
                items.addAll(list.getItems());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                // error case
                switch (response.code()) {
                    case 404:
                        getData2("news");
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        getData2("news");
                        break;
                    default:
                        getData2("news");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PostList> call, Throwable t) {

            if (t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                noNet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else if (t instanceof IOException) {
                noNet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                noNet.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            getData2("news");

        }
    });
```

Here sometimes this 'if (t instanceof UnknownHostException)' is being called again and again even when internet is connected and working fine.

Comment: That means that your domain name is not being resolved. Whatever domain name server the user is connected to is having difficulty getting the DNS information from upstream. If you have a Web site at `www.ddbharat.com`, you might ask the users if they are able to visit that in their mobile Web browser.

Comment: My domain www.ddbharat.com has cloudflare DNS which reduces load on my server. Could this be the reason behind this DNS error? Because over 90% users never get this problem, only a few get this problem.

Comment: Cloudflare should be pretty good -- the problem more likely is with the mobile carrier or other ISP that the user is connected to.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are absolutely right, because I am sure I get UnknownHostException error and this seems definitely a host resolving issue. So what do you suggest what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Provide a more specific error message to the user, perhaps. There is nothing that you can really do about it, in terms of your code or your DNS configuration.

Comment: Presently I am showing them error message that their internet is not connected. Can I increase timeout time? Will that make a difference?

Comment: You already have a 30-second connect timeout. If the DNS isn't resolving by then, it is unlikely to resolve. You could treat `UnknownHostException` differently from `IOException` and show dedicated messages for each.

Comment: IOException error only comes when there is a problem in JSON data, so i never show an error for that, I simply redirect the user to another backup url to fetch the results. I don't know what error message I should show for UnknownHostException error. Is 'Your Internet is not working, please switch on your moble data or connect to wifi' message not correct? Can you suggest an appropriate response? I am so grateful for your help.

Comment: "IOException error only comes when there is a problem in JSON data" -- you will get that exception for timeouts and other network issues as well. "Can you suggest an appropriate response?" -- how about "Your current ISP cannot find our domain name -- you might wish to try another network". As you note, their Internet connection is fine ("even when they are connected online"), so telling them to turn on their Internet connection will confuse them. Instead, get a bit more specific ("cannot find our domain name"). If you think "domain name" is too technical, perhaps use "cannot find our site".

Comment: Many thanks to you for your help. This issue was bugging me for many days. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I often get this error when I change internet connections on my device, and run the same app on more than one connection. The solution for me is to run "Invalidate Caches and Restart" in Android Studio.